# Присвоить строке указателю значение

Tags: c++, строки

Допустим у меня есть

```
std::string* path;
```

Могу ли я как то присвоить значение переменной?

Comment: `std::string* path = new std::string("Hello");`

Comment: А что сложного? `string str = "hello"; string* path = &str;`

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен не указатель, а ссылка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Какое** значение?
Например, `nullptr` годится? Потому что переменная здесь - **указатель** на строку, и вы можете присвоить ей значение адреса строки (или `nullptr`).

А вот (*корректный*) адрес строки - можно получить и как адрес имеющейся строки, типа

```
string s("Hello");
string* p = &s;
```

и как созданный с помощью `new` -

```
string* p = new string("Hello");
```

Примерно так. Только надо не запутаться, где память надо освобождать, а где нет...